# Unable to install clang-15* packages on Ubuntu 22.04 due to held broken packages

Tags: apt, kernel, dependencies, clang

I've been trying to install `clang-15-dbgsym` and such packages but I've been unable to due to the following error:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 clang-15-dbgsym : Depends: clang-15 (= 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried finding what the packages are but to no avail.

```
$ uname -r                                                                                         
5.16.0-051600-generic

$ lsb_release -a                                                                                   
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

$ sudo apt -f install                                                                         

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Is there anything that looks amiss or that I should be looking into. I tried upgrading the kernel but couldn't find any way to upgrade past 5.16.

```
$ apt policy clang-15-dbgsym                
clang-15-dbgsym:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
     1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-proposed/main amd64 Packages
     1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2 500
        500 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
```

```
sudo apt update                              
[sudo] password for groot: 
Get:1 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease [2,316 B]
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:3 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial/main amd64 Packages [19.4 kB]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                         
Hit:5 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease                                     
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/starlabs/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease             
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]        
Hit:8 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x focal InRelease                     
Get:9 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease [2,861 B]           
Get:10 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy InRelease [41.3 kB]                       
Hit:11 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease                        
Get:12 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security InRelease [7,553 B]
Get:13 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-updates InRelease [7,459 B]
Get:14 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security InRelease [7,453 B]
Get:15 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates InRelease [7,452 B]
Get:16 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease [23.8 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [108 kB]  
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]      
Get:19 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable/steam Sources [592 B]
Get:20 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable/steam amd64 Packages [1,143 B]
Get:21 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable/steam i386 Packages [1,339 B]
Get:22 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security/main i386 Packages [25.0 kB]
Get:23 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security/main amd64 Packages [29.9 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [994 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [469 kB]                                          
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main Translation-en [211 kB]                                          
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [101 kB]                                   
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates i386 Contents (deb) [28.3 MB]                            
Get:29 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [33.8 kB]          
Get:30 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-updates InRelease [41.3 kB]                                                          
Get:31 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages [2,204 B]                           
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates amd64 Contents (deb) [57.1 MB]                                        
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [14.0 kB]                                   
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [748 kB]                                    
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 Packages [27.1 kB]                                    
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted Translation-en [116 kB]                                    
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages [607 kB]                                       
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [899 kB]                                      
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe Translation-en [180 kB]                                      
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [269 kB]                               
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [18.6 kB]                               
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [24.1 kB]                                   
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]                              
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages [40.9 kB]                                       
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main Translation-en [10.2 kB]                                       
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,976 B]                                
Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [12.5 kB]                            
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages [280 kB]                                          
Get:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [731 kB]                                         
Get:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main Translation-en [147 kB]                                         
Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [41.4 kB]                                 
Get:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security amd64 Contents (deb) [50.8 MB]                                       
Get:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security i386 Contents (deb) [24.8 MB]                                        
Get:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [9,016 B]                                  
Get:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [705 kB]                                   
Get:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted Translation-en [110 kB]                                   
Get:57 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe i386 Packages [520 kB]                                      
Get:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [717 kB]                                     
Get:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe Translation-en [118 kB]                                     
Get:60 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [18.5 kB]                             
Get:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [14.2 kB]                              
Get:62 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-proposed InRelease [41.4 kB]                                                           
Get:63 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [64.0 kB]                                                   
Get:64 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [137 kB]                                                   
Get:65 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages [43.7 kB]                                               
Get:66 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [128 kB]                                               
Get:67 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-proposed/main amd64 Packages [31.8 kB]                                                 
Get:68 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-proposed/main i386 Packages [11.4 kB]                                                  
Get:69 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-proposed/universe i386 Packages [12.7 kB]                                              
Get:70 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-proposed/universe amd64 Packages [20.0 kB]                                             
Fetched 170 MB in 43s (3,917 kB/s)                                                                                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
53 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

```
$ apt list --upgradable                                                                       
Listing... Done
alsa-ucm-conf/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.5 all [upgradable from: 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.4]
clang-15-doc/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 all [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
clang-15-examples/jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
clang-15/jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
clangd-15/jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
distro-info-data/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.52ubuntu0.3 all [upgradable from: 0.52ubuntu0.2]
exo-utils/jammy-apps-security 4.16.3-1ubuntu0.1~esm1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.16.3-1]
gdm3/jammy-updates 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.0-1ubuntu7]
gh/unknown 2.27.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.25.0]
gir1.2-gdm-1.0/jammy-updates 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.0-1ubuntu7]
gnome-settings-daemon-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 42.1-1ubuntu2.2 all [upgradable from: 42.1-1ubuntu2.1]
gnome-settings-daemon/jammy-updates 42.1-1ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.1-1ubuntu2.1]
google-chrome-stable/stable 112.0.5615.49-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 111.0.5563.146-1]
im-config/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.50-2ubuntu22.04.1 all [upgradable from: 0.50-2]
ldap-utils/jammy-updates 2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libclang-common-15-dev/jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libclang-cpp15/jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libclang1-15/jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libexo-2-0/jammy-apps-security 4.16.3-1ubuntu0.1~esm1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.16.3-1]
libexo-common/jammy-apps-security,jammy-apps-security 4.16.3-1ubuntu0.1~esm1 all [upgradable from: 4.16.3-1]
libgdm1/jammy-updates 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.0-1ubuntu7]
libldap-2.5-0/jammy-updates 2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libldap-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 all [upgradable from: 2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libllvm15/jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libllvm15/jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libnss-systemd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.7]
libpam-systemd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.7]
libsystemd0/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.7]
libsystemd0/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 i386 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.7]
libudev1/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.7]
libudev1/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 i386 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.7]
llvm-15-dev/jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
llvm-15-linker-tools/jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
llvm-15-runtime/jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
llvm-15-tools/jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
llvm-15/jammy-updates 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2]
python3-tz/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2022.1-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 all [upgradable from: 2022.1-1ubuntu0.22.04.0]
signal-desktop/xenial 6.14.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.12.0]
steam-launcher/unknown,unknown 1:1.0.0.76 all [upgradable from: 1:1.0.0.75]
steam-libs-amd64/unknown 1:1.0.0.76 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:1.0.0.75]
steam-libs-i386/unknown 1:1.0.0.76 i386 [upgradable from: 1:1.0.0.75]
sudo/jammy-updates,jammy-security 1.9.9-1ubuntu2.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.9.9-1ubuntu2.3]
systemd-oomd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.7]
systemd-sysv/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.7]
systemd-timesyncd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.7]
systemd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.7]
thunderbird-gnome-support/jammy 1:102.10.0+build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:102.9.1+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1]
thunderbird-locale-en-gb/jammy,jammy 1:102.10.0+build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1 all [upgradable from: 1:102.9.1+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1]
thunderbird-locale-en-us/jammy,jammy 1:102.10.0+build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1 all [upgradable from: 1:102.9.1+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1]
thunderbird-locale-en/jammy 1:102.10.0+build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:102.9.1+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1]
thunderbird/jammy 1:102.10.0+build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:102.9.1+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1]
tzdata/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security 2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0 all [upgradable from: 2022g-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
udev/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.7]
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt policy clang-15-dbgsym` to your question

Comment: And `sudo apt update` please too.

Comment: added the requested output

Comment: It appears that you have the `proposed` repos enabled. That can be problematic. Why did you enable them?

Comment: I have no recollection of enabling them. I may have done it a while back (this system has gone through many upgrades). Is there an easy way to disable them?

Comment: Maybe with apt pinning you have a chance but backup your important data before.